# How to call on a function in a if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I can't figure out how the function showInputE() isn't being prepossessed.
I have some if statements within a function. If the if statements are true then they should preform a function. I want the functions to hide or show the the inputs in the easyAssignments div, depending on what the user inputs in numEAI. (Example: user inputs 3, only 3 input boxes will show) However when i click the enter button nothing appears to happen.

```
   <div id ="numEA">
  <p>How many easy assignments do you have to do today?</p>
  <input min="0" max="5" type="number" id="numEAI">
  <button class="w3-button w3-red" onclick="showInputE()">Enter</button>
</div>


<div id="easyAssignments">
    <p>What easy assignments do you have to do today?</p>
      <input type="text" id="easyA1">
      <input type="text" id="easyA2">
      <input type="text" id="easyA3">
      <input type="text" id="easyA4">
      <input type="text" id="easyA5">


</div>

<script>



  /* START of show input functions */

  function onlyShowInput1(){
      document.getElementById("easyA2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA5").style.display = "none";
      }
  function onlyShowInput2(){
      document.getElementById("easyA3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA5").style.display = "none";
      }


  /* END of show input functions */

  function showInputE(){
  var numEAI = document.getElementById('numEAI');

    if (numEAI === 1){
        onlyShowInput1();
    } else if (numEAI === 2){
        onlyShowInput2();
      }

  }

</script>
```

Comment: you need to use `numEAI.value` in the conditional. `if (numEAI.value === '1'){...`

Comment: You should use == not === as the values may not be of the same object type.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to:

```
function showHide(n) {
  let inputs = document.getElementById("easyAssignments").querySelectorAll("input");
  let item = 0;
  inputs.forEach(function(i) {
    item++;
    if (item <= n) {
      i.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
      i.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
function showInputE(){
  var numEAI = document.getElementById('numEAI').value;
  showHide(numEAI);
}
```

As all of the input items are named with sequential ids, you can switch the display style depending on whether or not the id matches "easyA" + numEAI.  There's no need to have a function for each input item.

Comment: While this code works, it does not answer the question, which is why the OP's conditional is not working. It would be better to explain why it is not working before providing unrelated code.

Comment: I did in my earlier comment - the reason was the === instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

You are currently comparing a DOM element to a number in your `if` statement.

In order to test the value contained in the element you can retrieve it using `numEAI.value`. This returns a string so if you are going to use `===`, which tests for equality of value *and* type, you need to compare it to a string `if (numEAI.value === '1')`, otherwise to just test equality of value use `==`.

```js
/* START of show input functions */

  function onlyShowInput1(){
      document.getElementById("easyA2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA5").style.display = "none";
      }
  function onlyShowInput2(){
      document.getElementById("easyA3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("easyA5").style.display = "none";
      }


  /* END of show input functions */

  function showInputE(){
  var numEAI = document.getElementById('numEAI');

    if (numEAI.value === '1'){
        onlyShowInput1();
    } else if (numEAI.value == 2){
        onlyShowInput2();
      }
  }
```

```html
<div id ="numEA">
  <p>How many easy assignments do you have to do today?</p>
  <input min="0" max="5" type="number" id="numEAI">
  <button class="w3-button w3-red" onclick="showInputE()">Enter</button>
</div>


<div id="easyAssignments">
    <p>What easy assignments do you have to do today?</p>
      <input type="text" id="easyA1">
      <input type="text" id="easyA2">
      <input type="text" id="easyA3">
      <input type="text" id="easyA4">
      <input type="text" id="easyA5">


</div>
```